# UITable view to detail view JSON parsing with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, ios, json, youtube-api, afnetworking

I managed to parse data from YouTube API on UITable view using AFNetworking but i cant figure out how to use

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How do i pass the JSON data to the next view ?

Here is the link to the file: [google drive](http://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B1EPIKZI6a5sSzVWdXh6VU1POWs/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my code

```
#import "KKViewController.h"

#import "AFNetworking.h"


#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

@interface KKViewController ()

@end

@implementation KKViewController

@synthesize  movies = _movies, count = _count;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL0l3xlkh7UnvLdr0Zz3XZZuP2tENy_qaP?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {



        self.movies = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];

        // NSLog(@@, video)

        //


        self.count = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"];
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];





    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{



    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (self.movies && self.movies.count) {
        return self.movies.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSDictionary *countt = [self.count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [movie objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [movie objectForKey:@"uploader"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[countt objectForKey:@"hqDefault"]];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this sample code will help you to accomplish your needs easily.
Please ask if anything look ambiguous to you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
 {
  [self.leadsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  id object = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.leadforLeadDetails = (Lead*)object;

self.selectedLeadID = self.leadforLeadDetails.ID;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openLeadDetails" sender:self];


// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
   //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView2 indexPathForCell:sender];
   //[self.tableView2 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"openLeadDetails"])
{
       LeadsDetailsTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       destViewController.dictLeadDetails = self.dictLeadDetails;

       destViewController.leadID = self.leadforLeadDetails.ID;
       destViewController.Name = self.leadforLeadDetails.Name;
       destViewController.leadDetails.ID = self.leadforLeadDetails.ID;
       destViewController.leadDetails.Name = self.leadforLeadDetails.Name;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either:

1. Define a segue in your storyboard's prototype for the cell in question and you don't have to write a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at all;
2. Have `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do a `performSegueWithIdentifier` (giving it the unique string "storyboard identifier" that you set up for your segue in the storyboard;

You can then write a `prepareSegue` that would look at the table's [`indexPathForSelectedRow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow) to identify what row was selected. You can then grab the appropriate information from your app's model and set the appropriate property in the `destinationViewController`.

You could also have `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do an `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` set the property, and then do the appropriate `pushViewController` or `presentViewController`, but I personally prefer the above techniques that leverage the segues you've defined in your storyboard.

Comment: i defined a segue. but how do i pass the JSON data associated with that cell. I am parsing video titles from a youtube channel. I want to pass the description to the next view.

Comment: 1. Grab indexPath.row via `indexPathForSelectedRow`; 2. `NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`; 3. `NSString *title = [movie objectForKey:@"title"];`; 4. pass `title` to your destinationController. Do you have a `@property` in the destination controller` to hold the `title`?

Comment: @user1951876 I've sent you a [pull request](https://github.com/miznat/youtube/pull/1) that illustrates my previous point. The only difference is that, instead of just passing the title, I passed the whole `NSDictionary` entry associated for that tableview row. In terms of discussion of how to pass data between controllers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers.